# Android Drawer with Navigation checks wrong menu item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

I use Navigation Component with Drawer. It starts with correct field:
[image]

Then I click on any menu and it changes to correct navigation fragment:
[image]

But if I click on same item or any other it always switches to correct navigation fragment, but drawer menu resets selection to first element (first screenshot).

Here's how I init drawer and navigation:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
setSupportActionBar(root.toolbar)
val nav_controller = findNavController(R.id.navigation)
appbarCfg = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
  R.id.nav_group,
  R.id.nav_help,
  R.id.nav_video,
  R.id.nav_settings
), root)
setupActionBarWithNavController(nav_controller, appbarCfg)
root.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.lblue))
root.drawer.setupWithNavController(nav_controller)
```

Navigation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/nav_group" <!-- issue was here. -->
  app:startDestination="@id/nav_group"
  >

  <!-- group. -->
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_group"
    android:name="***.model.fragment.GroupFragment"
    android:label="@string/drawer_navigation_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_group"
    >

  </fragment>

  <!-- help. -->
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_help"
    android:name="***.model.fragment.HelpFragment"
    android:label="@string/drawer_navigation_help"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help"
    >

  </fragment>

  <!-- video. -->
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_video"
    android:name="***.model.fragment.VideoFragment"
    android:label="@string/drawer_navigation_video"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_video"
    >

  </fragment>

  <!-- settings. -->
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:name="***.model.fragment.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="@string/drawer_navigation_settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings"
    >

  </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Drawer menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:showIn="navigation_view"
  >

  <group
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    >

    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_group"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
      android:title="@string/drawer_navigation_home"
      />

    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_eye"
      android:title="@string/drawer_navigation_help"
      />

    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_video"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
      android:title="@string/drawer_navigation_video"
      />

    <item
      android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_gear"
      android:title="@string/drawer_navigation_settings"
      />

  </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Use `appbarCfg = AppBarConfiguration(......, drawerLayout)`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti root is Kotlin synthetic for my DrawerLayout.

Comment: Ops, sorry my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Issue was with id collisions. I had my navigation xml have id="@+id/nav_group" when I had fragment with same id.